# Generating an array of all property chains in a deep object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

Hey all, long time read but first time poster.  I've tried for the past few days trying to solve a logic problem and am having no luck was hoping some one who is good with recursion logic can help me out.

Basically i want to generate an array that contains arrays of all the nested properties of an object in javascript.  For an example:

`{a:'b',c:{d:{e:'f',g:'h'}},i:'k'}`

should return

`[['a'],['c','d','e'],['c','d','g'],['i']]`

I've tried doing recursion with various for/while loop but get hopelessly lost in the logic :/

Any help would be appreciated.
If there's a better way to describe my problem please let me know and i'll update this post.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it would be to write the recursive "chain builder" so that it took a callback, so that the callback could build the outer list.

```
  function findChains(obj) {
    function chainFrom(chain, obj, atEnd) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object') atEnd(chain);
        else {
            for (var pn in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(pn)) {
                    chain.push(pn);
                    chainFrom(chain, obj[pn], atEnd);
                    --chain.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var rv = [];
    chainFrom([], obj, function(chain) {
        rv.push(chain.slice(0));
    });
    return rv;
  }
```

Possibly that's a little overkill, and the callback could just be hard-coded rather than passed in (and down) as an argument.

Comment: Just tried your solution on a few test cases and everything looks good.  greatly appreciate the help man.  The logic was breaking my mind.  Out of curiosity how did you figure out the logic?  is there some system to figuring out recursion?

Comment: Well, generally what you do is think about the work you need to do, and how it's different when your at the end of a sequence of recursive calls versus when you're not. In this case, the "end" comes when the value of a property turns out not to be an object.  When it *is* an object, then it's time to add to the chain each sub-property, so that's the recursive step.  It takes some practice to get used to thinking that way. Learning Erlang is a fun way to practice, because in Erlang there's no looping -- just recursion!

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it recursively within one function, although I'm not sure whether that's any less overkill than the above method.

```
var obj = {a:'b',c:{d:{e:'f',g:'h'}},i:'k'};

function dig(obj) {
  var temp = [];

  if (typeof obj == "object") {
    for (var key in obj) {
       var a = dig(obj[key]);
       if (a.length !== 0) {
         for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           a[i].unshift(key);
           temp.push(a[i]);
         }
       } else {
         temp.push([key]);
       }
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

var arr = dig(obj);
```

Here's a working example in jsfiddle that shows what `arr` winds up containing:

http://jsfiddle.net/VZwaR/1/

It should work fine no matter how deep the associative array is.

Comment: checked and this works as well.  Thanks for your work.  Would upvote but isn't letting me.  As far as correct answer, either one of those posted work, but am unsure which is 'better'.

Comment: No worries, I wanted to see if I could still do this kind of stuff. What I like about Pointy's though is that it's straightforward -- especially if you just hardcode the `rv.push(chain.slice(0))` part -- although in speed terms mine will probably be a wee bit faster (e.g. no `--chain.length`, which is on an array).